# How to validate array for negative # and alpha input in Python

Tags: python, validation

I'm trying to validate an array of user inputs (pints of blood collected per hour over 7 hours) for negative numbers, spaces, and/or letters. Currently, with an if statement checking user input is below 0, the program receives type error: "'<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'."

```
inputPints = []
totalPints = 0
hours = ["#1", "#2", "#3", "#4", "#5", "#6", "#7"]

def userInput():
    for hour in hours:
        inputPints.append(int(input("Enter pints collected for hour {}: ".format(hour))))
        if inputPints<0:
            inputPints.append(int(input("Please enter a whole number {}: ".format(hour))))
userInput()

def userOutput():
    print("")
    print("Average number of pints donated is: ", "{:.2f}".format(import_functions.averagePints(totalPints, 7)))
    print("Most pints donated is: ", import_functions.maxPints())
    print("Least pints donated is: ", import_functions.minPints())
    print("")
userOutput()
```

Comment: Are you looking for `if len(inputPints) < 0`? Because you're comparing a list with the integer `0`.. Just as the error says. Or are you looking for `if len(inputPints[-1]) < 0` if the last input is length below zero?

Comment: Why do you perform the check *after* having appended the input already? How do you want to recover from the erroneous value? How do you want to deal with repeated incorrect input?

Comment: Great questions. I honestly couldn't tell you as I'm new to Python as of about 6 weeks ago. I've tried the length function and it returns no errors, but it doesn't show the user they are inputting an invalid integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should define your `userInput()` method like this …

```
def userInput():
    for hour in hours:
        user_input = -1
        while user_input < 0:
            try:
                user_input = int(input("Enter pints collected for hour {}: ".format(hour)))
            except:
                user_input = -1
            if user_input > -1:
                inputPints.append(user_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to validade your input.
To allow only the form #number.numbers, you can use the following for instance:

```
# test for matches on the regex expression. 
if len(re.findall('^#\d+.\d+$', "#-1.30")) > 0:
    # It is valid
    return true
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as Torxed commented, you are comparing an object of the "list" type vs an object of the "int" type. This rises the error:

> '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Yo should either validate user input before appending it to the list, or you could loop over the complete list to find wrong/right inputs.

Checking input before appending:

```
if int(input("Enter pints collected for hour {}: ".format(hours))) > 1:
    #This is ok
```

Checking input with complete list

```
for a in inputPints:
    if int(a) > 1:
        #a is OK.
```

I recommend you put those validations inside a try catch block, since the int() casting may break your code if it detects a non-castable character.

Hope this helps!

Regards